# Compilation of Sass using PrePros on Windows

Tags: css, sass, rubygems, compass-sass, prepros

I've inherited a project that uses Sass. I'm a 'NET developer so compiling CSS isn't really something ive had much exposure to. The previous developer told me (as I run on Windows and he runs on a MAC) to install prepros.

The steps I have run through are:

- Installed Ruby 2.3.0 for Windows
- Installed sass "gem istall sass"
- Installed compass "gem install compass"
- Installed sass-globbing "gem install sass-globbing"
- Installed compass-install-once "gem install compass-install-once"

I then opened Prepros and dragged in my "static folder", which has a structure like so:

- Static

  - css
  - js
  - sass
  - components (multiple files in this directory)
  - components.sass
  - screen.sass

screen.css looks like:

```
@import compass/reset
@import lubalin.css
@import variables
@import typography
@import main

@import components
@import elements
@import shop
@import blog
@import sponsor

@import theme
```

And the content of the screen.sass files looks like so:

```
@import "components/*"
```

In PrePros I changed the compiler to use Ruby Sass instead of Node Sass (on the advice of the previous developer).

Now, when I click on screen.sass in PrePros and click "Process file" I get the error message "Error: It's not clear wghich file to import for '@import "components/*"'.

I found some threads online that suggested that this was due to Windows, and that the wildcard should be changed to @import "components/*.*", however when I run with this command the error i get is "Error: File to import not found or unreadable: components/*.*"

Strangely, the file that prepros creates i.e. seems to understand perfectly which files to import for components.sass because I can see in the file the following section:

```
    {
  "path": "sass/components.sass",
  "imports": [
    "sass/components/_address.sass",
    "sass/components/_buttons.sass",
    "sass/components/_checkboxes.sass",
    "sass/components/_cookies.sass",
    "sass/components/_emailSignup.sass",
    "sass/components/_forms.sass",
    "sass/components/_moreContent.sass",
    "sass/components/_postCode.sass",
    "sass/components/_rte.sass",
    "sass/components/_search.sass",
    "sass/components/_separator.sass",
    "sass/components/_tooltip.sass",
    "sass/components/accordion.sass",
    "sass/components/equalHeight.sass",
    "sass/components/grid.sass",
    "sass/components/modal.sass",
    "sass/components/svgImages.sass",
    "sass/components/table.sass",
    "sass/components/_checkboxes.sass"
  ]
},
```

So it seems strange that PrePros can tell which files to import, yet when I try to compile it doesn't understand!

Lastly, the contents of the compass (config.rb) is:

```
require 'compass/import-once/activate'
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "css"
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "js"
```

Can anyone help a Sass newbie that;s out of their depth get PrePros up and running!? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your time in advance

dotdev

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, if you are a NET Developer you don't need PrePros, because you have Visual Studio good plugin-compilers. Try [WebEssentials](http://vswebessentials.com/download), it will do all the work for you. WebEssentials compiles SASS/SCSS files automatically when you save it.

Comment: I do get where you're coming from, however the reason I like the PrePros solution is that we are bringing a front-end developer on board soon and they probably wont be using Visual Studio...